# Simple Rails Conditional Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

Pretty simple I'm sure... but I can't figure out why it wouldn't work.

```
<tr<% if film.viewed == true %> class="viewed"<% end %>>
```

The film.viewed is a boolean but its not rendering the class if its true. Probably a syntax error. Any help? Also is there an easier way to write this without opening and closing? I tried using:

```
<tr<% if film.viewed == true puts class=\"viewed\" end %>>
```

Again probably a syntax error. I'm coming from PHP so I'm still learning.

Thanks.

Comment: How is it "probably a syntax error"? Are you getting an error message or not? Also, the `== true` part of the conditional is superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be something like the following...

```
<tr <%= 'class="viewed"' if film.viewed? -%>>
```

All boolean ActiveRecord columns get a question mark method that will return a true or false.  As MySQL stores booleans as 1/0, I usually use the question mark method just to be safe.

Comment: This may be new to Rails 3.1 (not sure, I'm a newb), but the above will not work properly. I tried putting double quotes in single quotes in the template, and Rails converts them to html entities (&quot;). So your source code ends up looking like: `<tr class=&quot;viewed&quot;>` Switching the code above to `<tr <%= "class='viewed'" if film.viewed? -%>>` fixes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easer to read:

```
<%= content_tag(:tr, "", :class => film.viewed? ? "viewed" : nil) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing film.viewed isn't true, but another value.

try something to the effect of

```
<tr <%= "class='viewed'" if film.viewed %> >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr <%= film.viewed ? 'class="viewed"' : 'class="notviewed" %> >
```

So, some notes.

- To do a full `if ... end` you would have needed a ";" or newline before the `end`.
- Do you actually have a local variable or parameter called `film`?
- You need `<%=` and not just `<%` in order to interpolate the final result of your template code.
- I imagine the erb template driver calls the `to_s` method on whatever result it gets, and since `nil.to_s` returns `""` then you are safe with a stand-alone false `if` statement, which has the effect as an expression of returning `nil`. But somehow having the expression always return a value one would be willing to see interpolated would seem to make sense.

Comment: or my least favorite keyword, `then`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do something like this.

```
<tr class="<%= film.viewed ? "viewed" : "" -%>"></tr>
```